# Can pinescript v5 create strategy base on other Buy / sell signal from other Buy / sell Strategy?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create another BTC Strategy based altcoin strategy. I plan to use the strategy on the Heikin Ashi Strategy in altcoin's.
Altcoin's tactical logic is to check BTC's strategy is buy/sell, if altcoin's HA Strategy signal also matches BTC's signal, then corresponding signal will appear. If the signal is opposite to the existing signal of BTC, ignore it. Can Pine Script do this? if  yes, can your give some exmaple code or link to script for who did it?
For example :
BTC uses RSI Strategy, if RSI says buy for BTC
then ALtcoin's has the same Buy signal, it shows Buy signal, and Altcoin's shows Sell signal, ignores it

thanks for reading

some exmaple code or link to script for who did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include in your altcoin strategy, you must include your BTC strategy and use :

```
request.security(symbol, timeframe, expression, gaps, lookahead, ignore_invalid_symbol, currency)
```

to get the value of the BTC